# Is there any recognition for doing assassination quests for the Dark Brotherhood after you complete the main questline?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If you do more of the random Thieves' Guild radiant quests than needed there is at least [some recognition](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thieves_Guild_%28faction%29):

> As you finish the additional jobs that Vex and Delvin give you, trophies of recovered items begin to fill the shelves too:
>
> Jeweled Candlestick appears after you complete 5 jobs.
>
> Ornate Drinking Horn appears after you complete 15 jobs.
>
> Golden Ship Model appears after you complete 25 jobs.

and so on. I want to know if there is anything similar for the Dark Brotherhood.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope. Just more gold, and the satisfaction that you serve Sithis and the Night Mother.